# Passenger not reading .htaccess from Document Root specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, phusion

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /home/fred/AptanaStudioWorkspaceSS/railsapproot/public
 ServerName 3strides.localhost
 <Directory /home/fred/AptanaStudioWorkspaceSS/railsapproot/public>
  AllowOverride all
  Options Indexes -MultiViews
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I get this apache error
(13)Permission denied: /home/fred/AptanaStudioWorkspaceSS/**railsapproot/.htaccess** pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

Apache did not visit **railsapproot/public** to read the .htaccess file.  I looked for it in railsapproot

When I change .htaccess permissions to 777 and copy to railsapproot I get similar errors.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I get this when the x-permission is missing on some subdirectory. Can you check that?

Comment: I've spent hours trying to figure this out.  Thank you for this hint.  I finally discovered the directory which lacked access.  Hallelujah!